# Configure wamp server to SVN on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: wordpress, apache, svn, wamp, visualsvn-server

I'm using a wamp server to publish a wordpress site and everything is ok, but now we are a team and all of us should work at the same time on a site and see the result online

I tried to configure VisualSVN with wamp server but the server wont start after adding the following lines to httpd.conf file

```
    LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so
    LoadModule authz_svn_module modules/mod_authz_svn.so
```

and the following

```
    <location /svn>
       DAV svn
       SVNParentPath c:/svn
       AuthType Basic
       AuthName "All my repositories"
       AuthUserFile c:/svn/passwords
       Require valid-user
    </location>
```

my question is: how to configure svn with wamp server??

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2014? Please, upvote it then. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear why you want/need to configure the WAMP server when you already have VisualSVN Server. VisualSVN Server includes Apache HTTP Server and you don't need to setup second HTTP server instance. VisualSVN Server configuration should be done via VisualSVN Server Manager console only, see the [Getting Started guide](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/).

**NOTE:** It's strongly discouraged to install any other web applications on VisualSVN Server's Apache HTTP Server. The Apache is configured to serve Subversion repositories only and must not be used to host other web services. Use another web server to host web apps.